"Donald Trump was the target of a second apparent assassination attempt Sunday when Secret Service agents ..." why I don't see a preposition?
I seen

Donald Trump was the target of a second apparent assassination attempt
Sunday when Secret Service agents opened fire on a gunman at his golf
club in West Palm Beach, Fla., where the former president was golfing
just a few holes away.

Source: The Wall Street Journal
"Donald Trump was the target of a second apparent assassination attempt Sunday when Secret Service agents ..." I don't see why a preposition is used in that sentence? Can you share with me few authoritative links about this situation?
Does it apply to North American English, and also British English?

Did you mean there's a missing preposition (before Sunday)?
If you think an adverb is missing, please tell us more.

Yes, this is my missing. I edited my question.

last is implied

In British English we would be much more likely to say 'on Sunday'.

@KateBunting - as would the New Yorker and New York Times.

This question is similar to: When can we omit the preposition "on" before weekdays. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. See also Should there be a preposition before a day (e.g. Monday)? and possibly others.

Edit
We could say ... assassination attempt on Sunday.
Omitting on in such usage seems quite common now; the first page here
already shows three valid hits of the usage attempt Sunday.  Despite that, I consider it quite informal and would use the preposition:

Donald Trump was the target of a second apparent assassination attempt [on] Sunday when ...


In AmE  on Monday we don't say "last Sunday" to refer to the Sunday that just passed, and if we do, we invite confusion.

Thanks, @TimR. I've edited my answer,  removing mentions of last.

I do say last Sunday for the Sunday that has passed. I know no other way to say it!

It is common to use days of the week without a preposition to refer to the day on which something happened.

Wednesday I had a fever and didn't go to work.
I had a fever and didn't go to work Wednesday.
I had a fever Wednesday and didn't go to work.

This is not unusual in conversation.  In writing, we are more likely to say "on Wednesday", "on Sunday", etc.
But in news articles, which strive for brevity, you will  see the prepositions omitted.
